# MySQL: Non-english characters messes up our SELECT queries

Tags: mysql, select, sqlyog, non-english

Have a problem doing select queries on our MySql database.

This query is working fine:

```
SELECT name FROM products WHERE brand = 'nike'
```

This one doesn't:

```
SELECT name FROM products WHERE brand = 'tøj'
```

There are 1,000+ products with brand = 'tøj', so I guess the problem is related to the non-english character.

Strange thing is that it's only when running the query via Wordpress/PHP that things doesn't work. If I run `SELECT name FROM products WHERE brand = 'tøj'` through SQLYog, I get the results that I expect.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: charset / collation of database / table / column; connection?

Comment: Also does product has ? instead of ø in brand column?

Comment: Try changing your table to UTF-8 and/or your text editor.

Comment: see this for starters http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-column.html then see  **Section2 / What does Show your Schema Mean?** of [What is Sqlfiddle and why should I care?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38899465) to help us to help you :p

Comment: Database/table is utf8/utf8_general_ci. Product has "ø" in the brand column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by converting the "ø" to "Ã¸" (based on http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html)

i.e. `SELECT name FROM products WHERE brand = 'tÃ¸j'` instead of `SELECT name FROM products WHERE brand = 'tøj'`

Answer (score 0):

Specify character settings per database. To create a database such that its tables will use a given default character set and collation for data storage, use a `CREATE DATABASE` statement like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Tables created in the database will use `utf8` and `utf8_general_ci` by default for any character columns.

Specify character settings at server startup. To select a character set and collation at server startup, use the `--character-set-server` and `--collation-server` options. For example, to specify the options in an option file, include these lines:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: Thanks. The database is already running the mentioned character set and collation.

Where do I set the character settings for the server startup?